# Why does ordinalityOfUnit use Monday as the first day of the week when using NSCalendarUnitEra?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to calculate the number of calendar weeks between two dates. I'm using the following code:

```
[cal ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear inUnit:NSCalendarUnitEra forDate:thenDate];
[cal ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear inUnit:NSCalendarUnitEra forDate:nowDate];
```

A date of 15-1-2017, a Sunday, results in 105192 weeks, and  16-1-2017, a Monday, results in 105193. That would indicate it is using Monday as the first day of the week. I have verified that `cal.firstWeekday` is 1. If I change the `inUnit` from `NSCalendarUnitEra` to `NSCalendarUnitYear` it works correctly. Is there a way around this?
I suppose I could subtract one day from both dates but that seems very hackie.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimenting, if you make sure all dates are in GMT and you set `cal` timeZone to GMT it works as one would expect.